# Equal operator will not work on positive numbers SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, iif

I am trying to return data based upon an IIF statement in table within SSRS. When I run this statement it returns as expected:

```
: =iif(Fields!WKBUCKET.Value =-1,1,0)
```

but if I run this

```
  =iif(Fields!WKBUCKET.Value =0,1,0)
```

it won't return any data. I know that I have data with where values are up to a positive 4 and it will not return anything.  I am sure it is something easy I am missing.

Here is some data

```
|NEED_QTY|  BKTMOD|RQCOM|   ITDSC|                  WEEKOF|             WKBUCKET|

150.000    -1     205701    2 FACER BLADE 1.38LG    2020-12-14 00:00:00.000 -1
86.000      1     205701    2 FACER BLADE 1.38LG    2020-12-28 00:00:00.000 1
132.000     2     205701    2 FACER BLADE 1.38LG    2021-01-04 00:00:00.000 2
```

Comment: what is the datatype of WKBUCKET ? Show some sample data as well please

Comment: It is an integer based upon the calculation I used SSMS. The formula I used in SSMS is a DATEDIFF formula.

Comment: NEED_QTY BKTMOD RQCOM ITDSC WEEKOF WKBUCKET
150.000 -1 205701 2 FACER BLADE 1.38LG 2020-12-14 00:00:00.000 -1
86.000 1 205701 2 FACER BLADE 1.38LG 2020-12-28 00:00:00.000 1
132.000 2 205701 2 FACER BLADE 1.38LG 2021-01-04 00:00:00.000 2

Comment: It *should* work as shown. When dealing with issues that don't seem to make sense like this, I make a table for the data along with the expression to look at the data. I see that none of the sample records meet the 'WKBucket = 0' criteria.

Comment: The sample data doesn't have any 0 but the bigger data does. I have even tried to do a case when in SSMS and reference a text name. The more I mess with it the more I think there is something going on with the data and what I am asking it to do.

Comment: If that's the case.. why not derive another column is sql by wrapping a case statement that returns a 1 or a 0 based on the wkbucket column and just use that in your report?

Comment: I was hoping to use those columns to calculate based upon the value. Thank you for everyone's help.